# My page was attacked via xss, but on ftp all files are not changed?

Tags: php, javascript, security, xss, code-injection

yesterday i noticed that sometimes on my webpage shows up javascript errors.
when i went to source code, i found that one of .js files was totaly replaced with a ton of porn links.

i checked the ftp for this file, but there was just old javascript file without any changes.
yet i go back to check source code via browser and indeed there was again original .js

today i visited my webpage again and the problem repeated.

- first visit showed me ton of porn pages
- cached .js file was hacked
- but after clearing browser cache js go back to oryginal

i checked all files on my ftp against my offilne version, but all files are without any change.

in last few years i was attacked by xss few times but in every case it was easy to diagnose and fix. but now i spend 12h and didnt find infection.

do you have any idea how to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely they've found an exploit inserting XSS data in your DB and / or CMS files, which then is displayed when you go to a specific page.

You seem to be using Quick CMS and it might contain some flaw somewhere, however if you've developed any custom functions yourself this might be where the problem is.

When you insert data into a DB always use the mysql escape function, and when you output the data from the DB on to the page use the php htmlentities() function, this will protect you from XSS attacks.

Comment: thx, but the problem is that page runs on flat file db instead of mysql, i checked this too and didn't find any injections.

i deleted from server all js files which was sometimes showing as infected and guess what... after page reloading those files showed in browser cache as infected again, but physically there wasn't any of them on ftp.

rewrite engine is turned off here. I'm confused.
now i removed from <head> all JavaScript references. and for now problem disappeared, but still its not solved.

Comment: Are you on a shared server? Maybe the server it self is compromised and they do this manually?

Comment: Well, you state that the files haven't been changed on the server so that is not the problem if that's the case. In general you can't really check if the server is the problem when you don't have root access to it.

There is something really strange with your problem, doesn't really make sense that none of your files hasn't been changed and the JS is still edited, something must be changed for an XSS attack to take place.

Answer (score 0):

XSS attack does not need to change files at server side, it uses specially formatted query link which your code then renders to the webpage due to not checking inputs correctly.

You just need to escape or check your inputs. Search for "how to prevent xss".

[Preventing Cross Site Scripting Attacks](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/09/27/preventing-cross-site-scripting-attacks)